# JBPM assign task to a specific user

Tags: task, assign, jbpm

I need to assign a task to a specific user.
Let me explain by an example
[image]

In this process the task has a POTENTIENTIAL_OWNER 'GROUP1'.
User 'JOHN' of GROUP1 work the task 'TASK' and ask to execute the script.

After the execution of the script the TASK must be put in status RESERVED, the actual_owner must be JOHN and POTENTIAL_OWNER must be GROUP1

Right now I am only able to put the TASK in status READY with 'JOHN, GRUOP1' as the potential owner setting actors and groups variable

[image]